# How to store Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportViewer object value to Azure Redis Cache

Tags: azure, caching, redis

In case of InProc session configuration, application is working absolutely fine. But, when using Azure Redis Cache, its throwing error.
Is there anything required to serialize/deserialize the object. If yes, then how can I do this ?

My code is:

```
Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportViewer RptViewer_x = 
    (ReportViewer)HttpContext.Current.Session["session variable name"];
```

Comment: Can you share more error details?

Comment: I am using the below Nu-Get package: Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.WebForms    Type 'Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportViewer' in Assembly 'Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' is not marked as serializable.

Comment: We want see error msg.

Comment: Type 'Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportViewer' in Assembly 'Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' is not marked as serializable.

Comment: I haven't seen any relationship between your code and redis cache.

Comment: My web.config configuration to connect with azure redis cache
<sessionState mode="Custom" customProvider="MySessionStateStore">
 <providers>
   <add name="MySessionStateStore" type="Microsoft.Web.Redis.RedisSessionStateProvider" host="xxx.redis.cache.windows.net" accessKey="xxx" ssl="false" />
 </providers>
</sessionState>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221999/discussion-between-roushan-and-jason-pan).